# C# Build with csc, Execute from Commandline - Getting Exceptions

Tags: c#, csc

I have built a dll with csc.exe by using:

```
csc.exe "/target:library" "/out:$($path).dll" "$($path).cs"
```

From the powershell console I run it with:

```
powershell.exe -command {[byte[]]$bytes = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes("$($args[0]).dll"); $assembly = [Reflection.Assembly]::Load($bytes); [ns.main]::Main();} -args $path
```

However when an exception occurs it just quits and prints nothing. I have to use try / catch in the code to trace down where it came from.

What do I have to change to get exceptions printed before it quits?

Comment: Perhaps you should change the target type from something other than library may be you should `/target:exe`? a library won't have the entrypoint set (even if you have a `Main` method.

Comment: _"I have to use try / catch in the code to trace down where it came from."_ what did you find when you did this?

Comment: An exe is not an option. Its not the point what I found. Im in process of developing so I found many exceptions like accessing lists on indexes that didn't exist. I want the exceptions to be printed.

Answer (score 0):

In the code I tried the event "UnhandledExceptionEventHandler" with AppDomain but that didnt work. You can however get the exception from the event log and $LASTEXITCODE is also set accordingly.

So I added this after the build and subsequent execution commands:

```
if ($LASTEXITCODE -ne 0)
{
  Get-EventLog -logname Application -EntryType Error -source ".NET Runtime" - 
  Message *powershell* -newest 1| select-object -property timegenerated,message | 
   format-list
}
```